# Treeview Directory reacts with Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, treeview

I have a treeview directory. The directory is an actual viewing of folders with files on it and beside the treeview of directory I have a datatable. 
The interface looks like this:

[image: Treeview]

When I click a treeview it will show its path through alert. Like this:( I clicked the runblack.png).

[image]

My question is how can I make the treeview react with the datatable beside. 
Like if I click the year the datatable will search all files with the same year. 
Then if i click the category below the year it will search the category with the year.

This is my code for the directory:

```html
<?php

function php_file_tree($directory, $return_link, $extensions = array()) {
 // Generates a valid XHTML list of all directories, sub-directories, and files in $directory
 // Remove trailing slash
 if( substr($directory, -1) == "/" ) $directory = substr($directory, 0, strlen($directory) - 1);
 $code .= php_file_tree_dir($directory, $return_link, $extensions);
 return $code;
}

function php_file_tree_dir($directory, $return_link, $extensions = array(), $first_call = true) {
 // Recursive function called by php_file_tree() to list directories/files
 
 // Get and sort directories/files
 if( function_exists("scandir") ) $file = scandir($directory); else $file = php4_scandir($directory);
 natcasesort($file);
 // Make directories first
 $files = $dirs = array();
 
 
 foreach($file as $this_file) {
  if( is_dir("$directory/$this_file" ) ) $dirs[] = $this_file; else $files[] = $this_file;
 }
 $file = array_merge($dirs, $files);
 
 // Filter unwanted extensions
 if( !empty($extensions) ) {
  foreach( array_keys($file) as $key ) {
   if( !is_dir("$directory/$file[$key]") ) {
    $ext = substr($file[$key], strrpos($file[$key], ".") + 1); 
    if( !in_array($ext, $extensions) ) unset($file[$key]);
   }
  }
 }
 
 if( count($file) > 2 ) { // Use 2 instead of 0 to account for . and .. "directories"
  $php_file_tree = "<ul";
  if( $first_call ) { $php_file_tree .= " class=\"dirlist\""; $first_call = false; }
  $php_file_tree .= ">";
  foreach( $file as $this_file ) {
   if( $this_file != "." && $this_file != ".." ) {
    if( is_dir("$directory/$this_file") ) {
     // Directory
     $flink="./$directory/$this_file";
     $dlink = str_replace("[link]", "$directory/". urlencode($this_file), $return_link);
     $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"hdir\" ><a href=\"$dlink\">" . htmlspecialchars($this_file)."</a>" ;
                    
     $php_file_tree .= php_file_tree_dir("$directory/$this_file", $return_link ,$extensions, false);
     
     $php_file_tree .= "</li>";
    } else {
     // File
     // Get extension (prepend 'ext-' to prevent invalid classes from extensions that begin with numbers)
     $ext = "ext-" . substr($this_file, strrpos($this_file, ".") + 1); 
     $link = str_replace("[link]", "$directory/" . urlencode($this_file), $return_link);
     $flink="./$directory/" . urlencode($this_file);
     $fsize = filesize ("$flink");
     
     $ftime=date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($flink));
     $php_file_tree .= "<li class=\"hfile " . strtolower($ext) . "\"><a href=\"$link\">" . htmlspecialchars($this_file) . "</a><br></li>";
    }
   }
  }
  $php_file_tree .= "</ul>";
 }
 return $php_file_tree;
}

// For PHP4 compatibility
function php4_scandir($dir) {
 $dh  = opendir($dir);
 while( false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)) ) {
     $files[] = $filename;
 }
 sort($files);
 return($files);
}
```

I want it like when the treeview is clicked I will pass a query to the datatable to search for the needed data.

Query example: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = 'from treeview' AND CATEGORY = 'from treeview' ... and so on

My datatable viewing of data from the database is just the usual javascript to php connection for select.

Comment: thx.. it works.

Comment: haha, you're welcome. but i also need answers for my question